# Sending telnet smtp data command and ending with a period does not work

Tags: linux, email, smtp, telnet, qmail

I am stuck in my SSH telnet session, trying to test an SMTP connection, but when I enter a period to submit the data of a test email - nothing happens. 
I can end the session with the <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> - but I want to submit the data, not close the session. What am I missing?

Ubuntu 16.04 Client. Debian 8 server. Qmail.

```
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
rcpt to: <nospam@test.com>

mail from: <testmail@test.com>
250 ok
rcpt to: <nospam@test.com>
250 ok
data
354 go ahead
From: Test_sender <testmail@test.com>
To: Test_receiver <nospam@test.com>
Subject: Just a stupid SMTP test

Just a test !

\r\n503 MAIL first (#5.5.1)<return linefeed doesn't do anything either)
^Q^S
-->.<------------------------------------
(single period on one line-formatting issue)

^C
^Q
quit
exit
bye
```

Comment: answer here [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698127/when-using-telnet-or-netcat-to-test-an-outgoing-smtp-email-i-cannot-end-message) had to add another 5 chars to post

Answer (score 0):

I re-installed all the programs as per the guide I am using, and gained the
desired functionality. the site is [qmailrocks](http://qmailrocks.thibs.com).